# Why we use 'being' and 'to be' at the same time?

Tags: sentence-patterns

Why we say like this when we meet someone?

1. John-"Thanks Mike for being here"
2. Mike- "John, you know I just love to be here".
   Why one uses 'being' and other 'to be'?.

Which one is correct? And why?

3. Chine is close to be a superpower.
4. China is close to being a superpower.

Comment: Mike *can* say "I love being here"

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence is correct(China is close to being a superpower)

"Close to" implies nearness. And since you cannot be near an *action*, "close to be...." is incorrect.

However *being* is the gerund(noun) form of the verb "be". It functions as a noun, so you can say "close to being...."

Comment: 'Close' is an adjective followed by a preposition 'to' which must be followed by a noun or a gerund.